# Obfuscating CSV

Tags: java, obfuscation, inputstream, bufferedreader

Is it possible to make a CSV reader similar to this

```
while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
            String[] values = line.split(",");
            for(String s : values) {
                data.add(s);
}
```

but instead of just a comma, have different splits for each line eg:

```
value/value;value=value
```

instead of just
    value,value,value,value

Comment: in short, quite easy yes, define an array of chars a ={';','/','['} etc and iterate over them, why are you trying to do this anyway?


you may end up with problems if any of the value strings contain one of the expected charters, and obviously the ordering of the chars needs to be the same on both ends.

Comment: @Waltzy all the input data is in my hands so ordering the chars won't be a problem. I was just thinking it make it a pain to reverse engineer the data if it was full of seemingly random line splits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`String#split` takes a regular expression, not just a String, as argument, so you could use an expression like `;|/|=|,` for splitting.

Comment: Yes. That is one way of doing the "or" in this case. The other way is using a character group with `[;/=,]` like the other commenters prefer.

Comment: say if I used an expression with multiple characters for the split such as `hello|there` would it only recognise "hello" or "there" as splits or would it also take any single character (eg: "h" or "t")

Comment: It would split at the character sequences. A single "h" would not match the regular expression as a whole, "hello" would.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can implement a reader for your *obfuscated csv*, but the file format is not CSV anymore and you'll have more problems to identify a set of separator characters (they must not be part of the values).

Easiest approach: write an encoder, that converts a legal CSV to your own dataformat and a decoder of the transformation back to legal CSV.

BTW - you still can decode with a single split command:

```
String[] values = line.split("[/;=]");
```

`split` takes a regular expression as an argument.

Comment: that sounds like a plan I want to store the CSVs in obfuscated form so I could write an encoder for my own use and then make the encoder part of the CSV reader right?

Comment: The decoder, to be precisely. Data -> CSVWriter -> Encoder -> Database and later Database -> Decoder -> CSVReader -> Data

Comment: Sorry I meant to say I would make the "decoder" part of the reader if that makes more sense.

Answer (score 1):

Split accepts regexp as a `String` argument. For example, this will split on any single of the characters you used in your example.

`line.split("[/;=]")`

Answer (score 1):

The split method of String can also be called using a [regular expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum). In your case, the fixed line of code will be:

```
String[] values = line.split("[,/;=]"); // specific chars you want to look for
```

or

```
String[] values = line.split("[^0-9]"); // everything except digits
```